# Error while enabling server side encryption policy for aws s3 bucket through cli

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket my-buxket-en --server-s
ide-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault":
{"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'
```

I am getting below error

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: {SSEAlgorithm:, AES256}}]}', [{ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefau
lt:
```

Kindly help me to resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have examined your AWS CLI syntax and I can confirm to the best of my ability there's nothing wrong with your syntax.

From the error, the issue is more related to the AWS CLI version i.e you are most likely using an older version of AWS CLI hence the old version is not able to pick-up the required parameter [server-side-encryption-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketEncryption.html#API_PutBucketEncryption_RequestSyntax)

Resolution Steps:

***1. Check the current version of your AWS CLI :***

```
aws --version
```

If the output is anything less than version (1.18.31) then proceed to upgrade your AWS CLI version as shown below.

***2. Upgrade your AWS CLI using pip (or pip3):***

To upgrade an existing AWS CLI installation, use the --upgrade option:

```
pip install --upgrade awscli
```

OR

```
pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```

***3. Upgrade your AWS CLI using [AWS Bundled Installer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-bundle.html):***

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Note: You may need to log out for the changes to take effect

Hope this helps!

Comment: whether i can access aws s3 only using aws ec2?whether we cant use from our system cmd?

Comment: its not mandatory to use EC2 to access AWS CLI. You can also use AWS CLI from your local system but you have to install AWS CLI first

Comment: Thanks a lot issue is resolved.I have another doubt what kind of automation we can make using PYTHON in aws s3

Comment: Glad to hear the setup is now working  Would you kindly accept my answer to assist other users as well

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add an answer that explains this for people using windows in case they find this and can't figure it out.

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket my-bucket-name --server-s
ide-encryption-configuration "{\"Rules\": [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\":
{\"SSEAlgorithm\": \"AES256\"}}]"
```

Needs to become

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket my-bucket-name --server-s
ide-encryption-configuration "{\"Rules\": [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\":
{\"SSEAlgorithm\": \"AES256\"}}]"
```

Once you handle the quotes in the json it works as expected.

Comment: thanks bud! That worked for me. I was using version 2.1.33 The only fix in your code is that it's missing a } just before the last "